# get data from sqlite and show it on table view

Tags: android, sqlite

SQL data to table view

I created a table in SQLIte. I want to show the data date wise in a table view

my db is like:

```
  id       date      name    TypeOfCustomer

   1     2/6/2019    x         new

   2     2/6/2019    y         old

   3     2/6/2019    z         new

   4     4/8/2019    a         old
```

i want to get out put/ display it on table view like:

```
date       New     old    total

2/6/2019    2       1      3

4/8/2019    0       1      1
```

Comment: you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: format please...

Comment: i just want the needed query to summarize  data by date and get the count of number of 'new' and 'old' 'Type of customers'

Answer (score -1):

You can fetch table data then create a string builder having HTML table view and then loop through data to append rows . Finally show the data in web view.

Comment: no i need to get that result into a Cursor object,so i need the query to fetch it from database